# Python: How can i find a directory that matches the first 3 characters from a string?

Tags: python, string, directory, character

I have a directory with 50+ directories inside which are named `"XXX - something"`

If I have `X = '123'`
How can I find the directory that starts with `'123'`?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on `glob`

Comment: Please show us any attempts at solving this problem, Stack Overflow is not code-writing service. You may start with reading about [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module.

Comment: Why this has to be Python?

Comment: @Nsh He does not ask you to write code. He is merely asking for a library capable of doing this task

Comment: @Piotr Dabkowski there's nothing in the question text that indicates that he's "merely asking for a library". "How can i find the directory that starts with '123'" does not mean "suggest a library".

Comment: @vape The code capable of doing that can be written in 2 lines. It's the question of type: "how can I split a string"

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski that's what I said. He is _not_ 'merely asking for a library', he is asking for code. It can be written in 2 lines by someone who knows how to code (or how to use Google) which this guy clearly is not. Which is what [@Nsh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2912340/nsh) was saying in the first place. I have no idea what you're still arguing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
[i[0] for i in os.walk('/path/to/directory/') if i[0].split("/")[-1].startswith(X)]
```

It will return a `list` in the folder `/path/to/directory/` recursively, if foldername startswith `X (your varibale)`

**OR**

```
[i for i,j,k in os.walk('/path/to/directory/') if i.split("/")[-1].startswith(X)]
```

Comment: Thanks, i ended up using os.walk.

but with a messed up code, i'll try with your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
import os, sys
folder = sys.argv[1]

folders = "ls -lh %s*" %(folder) 
os.system(folders)
```

run the code by `folderseach.py 123`

Where `123` represents the folder you'd like to find

Comment: This answer is not cross platform compatible.  This requires a binary named "ls" which is part of unix/linux/mac.  Specifically,  this will fail on windows.